# check substring with spaces in scanner

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

I am reading a file which has multiple lines, example of the content of this file is:

```
Reader : INFO - LOOP with sapces : 1
Reader : INFO - LOOP with sapces : 2
Reader : INFO - LOOP with sapces : 17
Reader : INFO - LOOP with sapces : 201
```

What I am trying to do is to get my program to read the number of lines that contains LOOP with spaces.

Here is my code:

```
Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(file);
int iterated = 0;

while (fileScan.hasNext())
    {

        String somestring = fileScan.next();

        if (somestring.matches(".*LOOP\\swith\\sspaces.*"))
            { iterated++; }

    }
    }

    System.out.println("number of times found is: "+iterated);
```

My issue is that my program is 0 for int iterated.

Comment: Can we know why you want to use `matches` instead of `contains`? Can your searched substring `LOOP with spaces` have different forms or is it fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I am trying to do is to get my program to read the number of
>   lines that contains LOOP with spaces

Try Like this.

```
if (scanner.nextLine().contains("LOOP with spaces"))
{ iterated++; }
```

- *nextLine()*

This method will read whole line.

```
String line=scanner.nextLine();
```

- *next()*

This will return next token in file means 
`next()` can read the input only till the space.

```
String token=scanner.next();
```

Answer (score 1):

[Scanner#next()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) returns a next element up to the next instance of the **delimiter pattern**, which is be default `"\\s"`, so it read up the next space, not line.

If you change `hasNext()` and `next()` to `hasNextLine()` and `nextLine()`, the delimiter is the system newline character, so it will read in a whole line at once.